# Flyway error on Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, flyway

I get the following error when I run `flyway.sh` on cygwin:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.googlecode.flyway.commandline.Main
```

The equivalent `flyway.cmd` works fine on DOS.

Has anyone got flyway running successfully via cygwin on Windows?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue using cygwin.
It's happening because the Java executable expects a Windows format classpath value.

Here's how I modified the flyway shell script to fix the NoClassDefFoundError. The two changes were: 1) double quotes around the -cp value and changing the ":" delimiter to ";".

Here's the final result:
$JAVA_CMD -cp "bin/flyway-commandline-2.2.jar;bin/flyway-core-2.2.jar" com.googlecode.flyway.commandline.Main $@ -consoleWidth=$CONSOLE_WIDTH

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to file a feature request with as many details as possible about the error and your environment.

Comment: That would be a great comment, but it's not an answer to the question. (Are you associated with the flyway project?)

Comment: I am the founder and project lead.